# Outlook 365 is prompting IMAP settings when adding a specific google domain account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap, prompt

I have been quite frustrated on this issue and Google has no solution for me.
I have created a domain in Google domains and added a users account in the workspace.

The first 3 days it works well. I managed to load accounts in Outlook with no issues.

I was playing with some DNS settings on the old domain which I also transferred to the Google domains and set up email forwarding. To which the Google domains prompted me that this will replace MX records. I was happy with the replace as it was set to different registrar (this is an old domain and nothing related to the new domain I have created in Google domains).

### This is my issue:

Whenever I load an account in outlook for this specific domain outlook goes into "set up manually" mode and when I click on Google it asks me to enter IMAP settings.

However for a different domain I have already created - it prompts me with google login.

I have went back and forth with Google domains and Google Workspace support team.
They advised me to enable the option under "Allow per-user outbound gateways" in the Apps --> Google Workspace --> Gmail in the Admin.google.com

I have made this change but no luck... still prompting me with the IMAP settings instead of google login screen. See below screenshots. prompts me with exchange, google options

[manually setting up of options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGLXR.png)

[Showing IMAP settings when clicked on Google option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF0Kf.png)

What it should do is prompt me with Gmail login window [Gmail login window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDa7w.png)

Please advise me what settings need changing?

Comment: Try opening Outlook 365 Email options from Control Panel, Mail.  More options there.

Comment: Looks like the issue is related to the domain which is not displayed asgmail.com. In order to further confirm if the issue is related to your current account, it's suggested that you could add another gmail.com account to check if there're any differences.

Comment: Is there any update about your case?

Comment: Hey team, I have raised this issue with Google also and they said that they will get back to me but they haven't and it has been over 2 weeks. I have no issues with any other domain... just this one domain it comes up with the imap settings!

Comment: The only work around is I use either GWSMO, or enter IMAP settings.

Comment: I have given up waiting on Google for this issue, although the last update they mentioned to me that they are going to liaise with Outlook team. I wonder what happened with that! Thanks for your help though. I also wonder if it might be anything to do with Squarespace taking over G-domains? Who knows. I gave up. lol.